# how to set text on checkbox column of jqgrid footer

Tags: checkbox, text, jqgrid, footer, show

I'm going to show the text on the footer in jqgrid.

For example, 
jQuery("#list")jqGrid('footerData','set', {check_total: total})

When check_total column is a checkbox, the total value is not shown on footer?

Is there any way to show  the text on footer?

Comment: How is the column check_total defined? Please, show us the code of the jqGrid and which version of jqGrid is used?

Comment: Thanks.
I found the solution from
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36598717/using-custom-formatter-for-footer-row